# Is there a way to find the rendering engine of a browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to know the way to find the rendering engine that a browser uses. Both using javascript and using about the browser that is available in the browser window.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189216/how-to-detect-browser-rendering-engine-in-javascript

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @RobW  because he could have googled it and found the answer almost immediately, and yet he wastes our time asking a question that has already been answered on Stack Overflow before.

Comment: @RobW - probably because (a) browser detection is generally considered a bad idea and (b) he hasn't demonstrated any attempt to solve the problem for himself.

Comment: Could some one correct me instead of down vote. I would be happy for.

Comment: check the link provided above. that will correct you.

Comment: Thanks Akshay. I got the answers by y down vote ?
Can you make it up vote ill remove the question.

Comment: remove the question the upvote would happen automatically

Comment: @ Spudley i asked2 question one is to check using javascript another is using the browser setting like how we check for the version of chrome.I thought my question is making sense.

Comment: @Akshay how? I couldnt get you.

Comment: @Domecraft in that case people should find the dupe and vote to close -- downvoting isn't appropriate there

Answer (score 2):

Not reliably.

Do feature detection instead of browser/engine detection.

John Resig: [Future-Proofing JavaScript Libraries](http://ejohn.org/blog/future-proofing-javascript-libraries/), note that this was written in 2007, but is still relevant today because people are apparently still asking about it.

Stackoverflow related: [Browser detection versus feature detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection)

Comment: Thanks Frits. So i believe my question makes sense unlike other who thought this question is not appropriate.

Comment: I don't think so. This question has been answered a million times already. That SO question I linked is 4 years old which, in terms of the Internet, is ancient history.

Comment: so do you think that i need to remove the question ?

Comment: @Sridhar yes, it's a dupe

Comment: @collum i have a question if i remove the post will the down vote disappear ?